# Why is UFW blocking port 80 when port 80 is allowed?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ufw

I have set up dozens of these Ubuntu 18 servers and have never had any issue with this before. I can't figure out for the life of me why it is blocking. Here is my UFW status:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When I go to the web page I have set up on the server I get "The site can't be reached, and here is the UFW log entry for the same time I try to access the page.

```
Jan 31 22:52:51 site-name kernel: [1035567.927062] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=x:x:x SRC=202.152.x.x DST=157.245.x.x LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=20626 PROTO=TCP SPT=44855 DPT=3422 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Let me know if there is anything else I can post that would help

Comment: Can you get to the site from the server itself?

Comment: Actually, regarding your log, UFW is not blocking port 80 but port 3422